# How to reduce ADC noise through PCB routing?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, adc, signal, infrared

I am routing a PCB board with some through hole IR emitters and transistors and I am trying to figure out placement of ICs/Op-Amps, as well as capacitor placement and route placements to reduce the noise as much as possible. I am printing on a two-sided PCB, without any planes.

Should I put power, ground, or analog reading signal lines on their own side to reduce noise? Are there any other precautions I can take to reduce noise of the analog line of the IR transistor?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't route digital power in the same area as the sensitive analogue signals, also the return paths for digital signals have to stay away from analogue side.

Comment: what do you know about how Electric fields will couple into high Z nodes of a circuit? or how magnetic fields will couple into the loops of a circuit?

Answer (score 3):

Separate the PCB into a quiet section and a noisy section.  Imagine that you've drawn out a quiet section on the PCB (or do it literally on a user layer, if your PCB layout tool will allow it).  Keep all of the digital and other noisy signals out of the quiet section.  Let the ADC straddle that dividing line, with it's analog side on the quiet side, and its digital signals & power on the noisy side.

You really want to be careful with grounds, too -- all the grounds running to parts inside the quiet section should have just one entry point to the noisy section, possibly at the ADC's "AGND" pin.  If you dump current from a noisy thing onto your nice quiet analog ground, it'll make, well, noise.